# Django signal receiving across apps

Tags: django, django-signals

I have a `main_app`, and `app2`. `main_app` is essentially a list of items with data, and `app2` has more information about said items.

`main_app` isn't supposed to know about `app2`, but `app2` can import from `main_app`.

Within `main_app/signals.py`, I have

```
import django.dispatch
mysignal = django.dispatch.Signal(providing_args=['uid'])
```

In `main_app/views.py`, I have a view which renders various `main_templates`, containing the details of the item, a view for editing, and one for submitting said edited data. The idea is that a signal is sent when each of those is called and, `app2` receives this. `main_template` uses the "`with`" call to get `template2` and that app's information.

In `app2/processes.py` I have the following:

```
import django.dispatch
from django.dispatch import receiver
import my models
from main_app.signals import mysignal, (mysignal2, etc)
```

Then for each method, I have

```
@receiver(mysignal)
def foo(sender, **kwargs) etc
```

OK... So, in `main_app/views.py`, if I have the line:

```
from app2.processes import mysignal, mysignal2 etc
```

Everything works smoothly. But I want to remove any reliance on `app2` in `main_app`. As far as I am concerned, `app2` is just importing these signals from `main_app/signals.py`.
But if I try to get rid of the above line and put the following into `main_app/views.py`

```
from main_app.processes import mysignal, my...
```

It doesn't work...I don't get an error but the data from app2 doesn't render into the template, and I really don't see why....Any ideas?

Comment: So nobody has any idea why although app2.processes imports the signals from main_app.signals, I have to import the signals into main_app.views via app2, rather than directly from main_app.signals?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your signal receivers in app2 are probably not registered. Simple check: put `raise Exception("I was imported!");` as the first line in `app2/processes.py`. You probably will never see that exception. You will have to make sure the signal receivers are being registered. You can do this by `import app2.processes` somewhere Django will look. For example in `app2/models.py`.

Comment: Nice! Thanks a lot. I put `import app2.processes` in `app2/__init__.py` actually as `app2/processes.py` already imports `app2/models.py`...Assume that's not absurd! Works perfectly anyway!